# Segmentation fault accessing loop variable

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, std

The following program seems to be causing a segmentation fault on the loop variable.

Could anyone help me understand what is going on please!

```
std::vector<int> Euler::Utils::sieve(int n) {
std::vector<bool> A(n, true);
using size_t = std::vector<bool>::size_type ;
size_t size = static_cast<size_t>(std::sqrt(n));
std::vector<int> result;

for (size_t i = 2; i < size; i++) {
    if (A[i]) {
        size_t i2 = static_cast<size_t>(std::pow(i, 2));
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
            A[i2 + j* i] = false;
        }
    }
}
for (size_t i = 2; i < A.size(); i++) {
    if (A[i]) {
       //Seg fault here.
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        result.push_back(i);
    }
}

return result;
```

}

Edit: The error is around the end at the result.push_back(i);

Comment: Give us enough code to reproduce the problem, please.

Comment: Could `A[i2+j*i]` be out of range?

Comment: @Dani it is not. The error seems to be happening in result.push_back(i)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: do A.at instead of A[], this will do bounds checking for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick glance, I see that the vector `A` is of size `n`. But in the first nested for loop, array `A` is indexed on `{i2 + j*i}`. This expression can evaluate to a number greater than `n` as `j` runs from `0` to `n-1`. So, `{i2 + j*i}` can exceed the capacity of your vector which may be causing the seg fault. Full code will help us in verifying this.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem i can only go up to sqrt(n)

Comment: The issue seems to be in the result.push_back(i)

Comment: On second look. You are right. A[i2 + j * i] is the problem. I updated the for loop to be             for (int j = 0; i2 + j* i < n; j++ ) {

Comment: Doesn't j go from zero to n? So if you multiply that with any value, it will overflow n at some point. I ran part of the code (just the nested loops) and it crashed there. Please provide with enough code so that we can reproduce the same.